# Adding "find/replace" box for footer text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been using a macro to find/replace text only in the footers. Currently, I manually edit the macro to adjust the find/replace text. I'd like to add a pop-up box to ask me what text to search for and what to replace it with. My attempts at doing this myself have not been successful.

Below is the macro I am currently using. Any thoughts?

```
Sub FooterDates()
    Dim oSection As Word.Section
    Dim oRange As Word.Range
    Dim var

        For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections()
            For var = 1 To 3
                Set oRange = oSection.Footers(var).Range
                oRange.Find.Execute FindText:="December 2015", _
                ReplaceWith:="February 2016", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                Set oRange = Nothing
            Next
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use two seperate Input boxes or create your own user form using the "add user form" button in the vba Editor.

Check out These links:
[Video](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJuo_g6fDQAhVJCMAKHWdKBlUQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8lKzMuk2nO0&usg=AFQjCNHXdsSPzwZh9YZJYqsdJm9nbpR2yw&bvm=bv.141320020,d.bGg)
[Tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-creating-a-word-userform-for-addressing-letters/)